# Не отображается код

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Во время отладки во второй части кода, visual начал серьезно тормозить, а программа повела себя не так как ожидалось. Я прервал выполнение, но код перестал отображаться, если я запускаю отладку, программа запускается, но код я не вижу, что делать? Код ну очень нужен, а сохранений нет
Visual studio 2017

Comment: Может просто вкладка с кодом была закрыта? или цвет текста стал таким же как и фона.

Comment: Откройте код обычным текстовым эдитором - файл исходного кода у вас же есть

Comment: Сбросьте настройки всей студии в настройках

Answer (score 1):

Два решения проблемы, указанные в комментариях:

1. сброс настроек
2. открытие файла через текстовый редактор